# New dispatch for isless function does not work

Tags: julia

I need to be able to compare instances of a struct named `Hijri`, so I have defined a new method for the `isless()` function as follows:

```
function isless(a::Hijri, b::Hijri)
    tuple_a = datetuple(a)
    tuple_b = datetuple(b)
    
    return tuple_a < tuple_b
end
```

`datetuple()` returns values of the `Hijri` struct as a tuple.

This works fine:

```
@show isless(a, b)
```

However, this one

```
@show a < b
```

throws an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Main.HijriConverter.Hijri, ::Main.HijriConverter.Hijri)
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::Any, ::Missing) at ~/Downloads/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/base/missing.jl:88
  isless(::Missing, ::Any) at ~/Downloads/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/base/missing.jl:87
Stacktrace:
 [1] <(x::Main.HijriConverter.Hijri, y::Main.HijriConverter.Hijri)
   @ Base ./operators.jl:352
 [2] top-level scope
   @ show.jl:1047
in expression starting at /home/jafar_isbarov/Documents/projects/hijri/HijriConverter.jl/src/HijriConverter.jl:1
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to import `isless` from `Base`:

```
import Base: isless
```

or use `Base.isless` (instead of `isless`) in my function definition.

```
function Base.isless(...)

end
```

This question was originally answered on [Julia Discourse.](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/new-dispatch-for-isless-does-not-work/74025/2?u=jafar.isbarov)

Comment: Yes, what you did originally was define a new function `isless` in your global scope that gets used instead of the separate `isless` function in `Base`. Requiring explicit module origin to extend another module's function is good because nobody wants to memorize every module's namespace just to avoid accidentally altering other modules' behaviors (and if you modify Base badly you could break the Julia session). For posterity, it's documented here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#using-and-import-with-specific-identifiers,-and-adding-methods